# Update listview row in asynctask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a listview with base adapter. each row in my list view contains image, title, download and view button and progress bar. initially progress bar and view button's visibility is GONE. when user press download button, progress bar should be visible. As soon as download is completed, download button should be gone and view button should visible.

My problem is: i am not able to change visibility of views from asynctask.

Here is my code.

```
public class PdfListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<PdfDetails> arylstPdf = new ArrayList<PdfDetails>();
    Context context;
    String extStorageDirectory;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Activity activity;


    public PdfListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PdfDetails> arylstPdf) {
        super();
        this.arylstPdf = arylstPdf;
        this.context = context;

        extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arylstPdf.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        activity = (Activity) context;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_pdf_list, null);

            holder.tvPdfTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvPdfTitle);

            holder.imgPdfImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgPdfImage);

            holder.btnDownload = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

            holder.btnView = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnView);

            holder.pbDownload = (ProgressBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.pbDownload);

            holder.tvProgress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProgress);

            holder.llProgress = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llProgress);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/pdf", arylstPdf.get(
                position).getPostTitle()
                + ".pdf");

        if (file.exists()) {
            holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        holder.tvPdfTitle.setText(arylstPdf.get(position).getPostTitle());

        ImageLoader objImageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        objImageLoader.DisplayImage(arylstPdf.get(position).getAttachedImage(),
                holder.imgPdfImage);

        holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 // NOT WORKING
                holder.llProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Async async = new Async();
                async.execute(Integer.toString(position));

            }
        });

        holder.btnView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                readPDF(arylstPdf.get(position).getPostTitle());
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgPdfImage;
        TextView tvPdfTitle, tvProgress;
        Button btnDownload;
        Button btnView;
        ProgressBar pbDownload;
        LinearLayout llProgress;
    }



    class Async extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        File file, folder;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String fileName = arylstPdf.get(Integer.parseInt(params[0]))
                    .getPostTitle();

            file = new File(folder, fileName + ".pdf");

            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            int count;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(arylstPdf.get(Integer.parseInt(params[0]))
                        .getAttachedPdf());
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;

                    publishProgress(Integer
                            .toString((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile)));


                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            holder.tvProgress.setText(progress[0]);
            holder.pbDownload.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // NOT WORKING
            holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a boolean flag in `PdfDetails` class change download and view button visibility in `getView` method.

so just change that boolean flag of that particular row in arraylist position.

and user `adapter.notifyDataStateChanged();`

Add getter setter method in PdfDetails class.

and in getView() method

use

```
PdfDetails detailBin = list.get(position);

if(detailBin.isDownloaded)
   // view button visible and download button hide
else 
  // download button visible and view button hide
```

and in postExecute()

```
list.get(position).setDownload(true);
adapter.notifyDataStateChanged();
```

Comment: hey @Sanket thanks.. It works!! but plz solve my one more prob. also i want to show progress bar while downloading.. with above code, i am not able to do so

Comment: yes for each row in which download process is going on

Comment: you should need to notify your listview from AsyncTask.

Comment: can you provide some sample code or any link related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating `holder` in the Adapter class itself can you let it be inside `getView` itself and pass it to `AsyncTask` constructor.

```
public class PdfListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<PdfDetails> arylstPdf = new ArrayList<PdfDetails>();
Context context;
String extStorageDirectory;
Activity activity;


public PdfListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PdfDetails> arylstPdf) {
    super();
    this.arylstPdf = arylstPdf;
    this.context = context;

    extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arylstPdf.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    activity = (Activity) context;
    final ViewHolder holder= null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_pdf_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvPdfTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvPdfTitle);

        holder.imgPdfImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgPdfImage);

        holder.btnDownload = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

        holder.btnView = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnView);

        holder.pbDownload = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pbDownload);

        holder.tvProgress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProgress);

        holder.llProgress = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llProgress);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/pdf", arylstPdf.get(
            position).getPostTitle()
            + ".pdf");

    if (file.exists()) {
        holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    holder.tvPdfTitle.setText(arylstPdf.get(position).getPostTitle());

    ImageLoader objImageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    objImageLoader.DisplayImage(arylstPdf.get(position).getAttachedImage(),
            holder.imgPdfImage);

    holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             // NOT WORKING
            holder.llProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Async async = new Async(holder);
            async.execute(Integer.toString(position));

        }
    });

    holder.btnView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readPDF(arylstPdf.get(position).getPostTitle());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgPdfImage;
    TextView tvPdfTitle, tvProgress;
    Button btnDownload;
    Button btnView;
    ProgressBar pbDownload;
    LinearLayout llProgress;
}



class Async extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    File file, folder;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public Async(ViewHolder holder) {
        this.holder=holder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String fileName = arylstPdf.get(Integer.parseInt(params[0]))
                .getPostTitle();

        file = new File(folder, fileName + ".pdf");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(arylstPdf.get(Integer.parseInt(params[0]))
                    .getAttachedPdf());
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                publishProgress(Integer
                        .toString((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile)));


                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        holder.tvProgress.setText(progress[0]);
        holder.pbDownload.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // NOT WORKING
        holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: after get the asynctask updated count set to viewholders textview android

Answer (score 0):

You can not do any changes for UserInterface(UI) in other threads(Asynctasks) other than Main ui thread..
So you need to follow this

```
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
        //Any UI changes can be done here            
        holder.btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.btnView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: he his doing in onPostExecute so there is not any issue

Comment: Ya ur crct..post execute runs on Main UI thread... i thought its done on DoinBackground